# NHibernate map class properties to query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map class to called a stored procedure with NHibernate

I have a class:

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    public virtual int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProductCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping for this class:

```
  <class name="OrderDetails" >
    <id name="OrderNumber" column="ID"/>
    <property name="OrderNumber" column="ID"/>
    <property name="OrderDate" column="OrderDate"/>
    <property name="ProductCode" column="productCode"/>
    <property name="ProductName" column="Name"/>
    <property name="Quantity" column="Quantity"/>
    <property name="Price" column="UnitPrice"/>
    <loader query-ref="GetOrdersByDate" />
  </class>
  <sql-query name="GetOrdersByDate" callable="true">
    exec [dbo].[sp_OrdersByDate] :DateFrom, :DateTo
  </sql-query>
```

When I call this query I get an exception

> Could not find a setter for property 'ID' in class 'OrderDetails'

How can I map this columns to class properties?

Comment: @RadimKöhler yeap I understand, but this is not a problem in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Ready to delete this ... if still no help...*

This is my SP (MS SQL)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_OrdersByDate]
    @DateFrom DateTime,
    @DateTo DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 1 as ID
    , '2011-01-01' AS OrderDate
    , 123          AS productCode
    , 'XYZ'        AS Name
    , 1            AS Quantity
    , 100          AS UnitPrice
END
GO
```

This is the mapping *(tested)*

```
<class name="OrderDetails" >
    <id name="OrderNumber"       column="ID" />
    <property name="OrderDate"   column="OrderDate"/>
    <property name="ProductCode" column="productCode"/>
    <property name="ProductName" column="Name"/>
    <property name="Quantity"    column="Quantity"/>
    <property name="Price"       column="UnitPrice"/>
    <loader query-ref="GetOrdersByDate" />
</class>

<sql-query name="GetOrdersByDate" callable="true">
    <return class="OrderDetails"></return>
    exec [dbo].[sp_OrdersByDate] :DateFrom, :DateTo
</sql-query>
```

And this is the query *(working)*

```
var query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetOrdersByDate");

query.SetParameter("DateFrom", new DateTime(2013, 10, 26));
query.SetParameter("DateTo", new DateTime(2020, 12, 26));

var list = query.List<OrderDetails>();
```

Comment: Thank you very mach. I'v understand the problem. I was using SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<OrderDetails>()) for query, so for NHibernate it was looks like OrderDetails should have a property of OrderDetails type.